# Can I buy train tickets in Georgia, Tbilisi (the country) 5 hours before the departure?

Tags: trains, tickets, georgia-country

I am going to Tbilisi from Yerevan and I will arrive around 14:00 and want to leave to Zugdidi on the same night. The train departs on 21:45.
So I like to purchase the tickets as soon as I arrive in Tbilisi

Comment: Taking a minibus from Yerevan to Tibilisi will be faster than the train.

Comment: I heard that they'll do the charting 4-6 hours before the train departure and I can't get tickets after it but I'm not sure about that. I guess I'll have enough time to get them, thanks!

Comment: This is a great question and please report back after you've done the trip. I could not find useful information on [Caravanistan](http://caravanistan.com/georgia/), [Caravanistan forum](http://caravanistan.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=15&sid=afbdb446f24625d607fab6aca34457d0), [Seat 61](http://www.seat61.com/Caucasus.htm), [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)#Get_around) nor [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Georgia_(country)#By_train_2).

Comment: [German Wikivoyage](https://de.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Georgien#Mobilit.C3.A4t) is fairly well-sorted and does not mention such a requirement to buy tickets far in advance but perhaps you could try to [get an online-ticket](http://tickets.railway.ge/login.aspx?lang=en-US)?

Comment: I initially answered here, but I realized it was out of scope for the question. If you'd like to know [how to get to Yerevan by minibus](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/77116/10280), I've created a question-answer for that. The marshrutka is likely cheaper, faster, and has great scenery.

Answer (score 7):

I see little sense in your worries about time limits when acquiring tickets in Georgian Railways offices. There are no essential grounds for it, moreover, tourists reported they bought tickets [half an hour before](http://forum.awd.ru/viewtopic.php?p=6899507#p6899507) the departure.
As it was kindly suggested by [mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts), online booking is optimal if you are not completely sure in ticket availability just-in-time. 
The only limitation, which exists is related exclusively to online booking:

> E-Tickets are to be sold **40 days** prior to date of train departure.
>   E-tickets booked less than **2 hours** before the departure time will not
>   be processed.
>   [Terms Of Use](http://tickets.railway.ge/terms.aspx)

Selling period starts 40 days prior to departure and ends 2 hours before. Nothing similar is known about offline selling.
The only assumption we can make is that offline selling period starts similarly as online (40 days before), but there are [evidences](http://forum.awd.ru/viewtopic.php?p=5137004#p5137004) that on-site offices start to sell tickets later than online ones (20 days before). However, this is informal info and shouldn't be treated as a rule of thumb.
The only limitation you should take into account is would you be able to board the train or not.